# Python Boto3 OpsWorks KeyError by getting CustomJson

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I try to get the custom json from my OpsWorks stacks with python and boto3. Getting the name is ok but if I want to get the CustomJson - KeyError. Don't have a clue why.

```
import boto3
import traceback

client = boto3.client('opsworks')

response = client.describe_stacks()

max_elements = len(response['Stacks'])

for i in range(max_elements):
    stack_Name = response['Stacks'][i]['Name']  # works

    try:
        stack_CustomJson = response['Stacks'][i]['CustomJson'] # KeyError
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

That's the console output:

```
$ python3 get_custom_json.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "get_custom_json.py", line 27, in get_opsworks_details
stack_CustomJson = response['Stacks'][i]['CustomJson']
KeyError: 'CustomJson'
```

Reading the docs from http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/opsworks.html#OpsWorks.Client.describe_stacks I don't see a difference between 'Name' and 'CustomJson' except that CustomJson is a JSON object. Do I have to transform it?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `KeyError` occasionally because the `CustomStack` element in the response is optional.  If a custom stack is specified for the stack, it will be returned.  Otherwise, the `CustomStack` key will not be there at all.  You should do something like:

```
if 'CustomStack' in stack:
    # do your thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick chat with a developer in my company. Got some basic introductions for getting better in coding and python and whatever (must loose some of my admin thinking).

Don't iterate about max_elements, better iterate above 'stack in stacks'.

```
for stack in response['Stacks']:
    print(stack['CustomJson'])
```

Now it works - I'll get the custom json from the OpsWorks stacks. But still there is the KeyError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "get_custom_json.py", line 22, in <module>
      get_opsworks_details()
   File "get_custom_json.py", line 18, in get_opsworks_details
      print(stack['CustomJson'])
   KeyError: 'CustomJson'
```

I'll check if I can fetch him again to see why that's happening.

[EDIT] Blind spot - if a stack has no custom json then the KeyError will occur.